# NoReverseMatch with get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a list of links made up of queryset objects. Clicking on each link should take me to that object's detail view. But I'm getting the following error:

`NoReverseMatch at /idea_tracker/shoppinglist/
Reverse for 'views.recipient_detail' not found. 'views.recipient_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

My model:

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthday = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'views.recipient_detail', 
            args=(), 
            kwargs={'recipient_id': str(self.id)}
            )

class Gift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, 
max_digits=6)
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Recipient, blank=True)
    purchased = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

My views:

```
def shopping_list(request):
    recipients = 
        models.Recipient.objects.prefetch_related('gift_set').\
        all().order_by('last_name')
    gift_list = models.Gift.objects.all()
    total = []

    for y in gift_list:
        total.append(y.price)
        total_price = sum(total)
    return render(request, 'idea_tracker/shoppinglist.html', {
        'recipients': recipients, 
        'total_price': total_price
        })

def recipient_detail(request, pk):
    recipient = get_object_or_404(models.Recipient, pk=pk)
    gift = recipient.gift_set
    return render(request, 'idea_tracker/recipient_detail.html', {
        'recipient': recipient
        })
```

My url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^shoppinglist/', views.shopping_list, name='shopping_list'),
    url(r'^recipient_detail/(?P<recipient_id>)/$', 
         views.recipient_detail, name='recipient_detail'),
]
```

My template:

```
<h3> Click on a Recipient to edit or delete:</h3>

    {% for name in recipients %}

    <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ name.get_absolute_url }}">{{ name.first_name }} 
        {{ name.last_name }} /

        {% for gift in name.gift_set.all %}

         <span style='color:darkblue'>{{ gift }}</span></a></li>

        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm rusty and not set up to validate this, but IIRC the named capture group in the URLs translates to a kwarg to the view - but your `recipient_details` function isn't set to take a kwarg named `recipient_id`. Try it as `def recipient_detail(request, recipient_id):` maybe?

Comment: This alone didn't fix the problem, but it needed to be fixed and was part of the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the name of the url pattern `recipient_detail`:

```
return reverse(
    'recipient_detail', 
    args=(), 
    kwargs={'recipient_id': str(self.id)}
    )
```

Your `recipient_id` group is empty. For example, you could match digits with:

```
url(r'^recipient_detail/(?P<recipient_id>\d+)/$', 
     views.recipient_detail, name='recipient_detail'),
```

Finally, you should change `pk` to `recipient_id` in your `recipient_detail` view to match the URL pattern.

Comment: This worked. I'm curious why changing 'views.recipient_detail' to just 'recipient_detail' in the reverse method worked? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) takes the URL pattern name, which in your case is `'recipient_detail'` since you have `name='recipient_detail'`.